# Создание потока изменения отображения UI в JavaFX

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Доброе время суток.

Для начала опишу ситауцию: Есть `TabPane`, на каждой вкладке которого находится объект `User`, который обновляется каждые `n` секунд (получая данные с сервера), и, если произошло изменение, он добавляет в `Set<User>` (один для всех вкладок) этого юзера.

В чём задача: Нужно обновление отображения моего `UI` для каждой вкладки, где данные юзера изменились. Вся логика уже написана, осталось только придумать, как сделать, чтобы обновление происходило каждые `k` секунд. Создавать новый поток не вариант, так как выбрасывается `Not on FX application thread` при попытке изменить состояние `UI-компонента` из другого потока. А крутить в этом потоке `while(true)` и там же засыпать на сколько-то секунд тоже не вариант, ибо засыпать будет основной тред приложения и всё просто зависнет.

Как можно всё реализовать, чтобы `UI` всё-таки нормально обновлялся?
Ещё раз повторюсь, основная логика уже написана, то есть я могу вызвать метод `updateUI()`, который запустит новый поток с использованием `Platform.runLater(Thread)`, обновит отображение и завершится.

Comment: Не понял... Так почему у вас не работает способ в фоновом потоке сделать `while (true)` со `Thread.sleep` и при необходимости лезть в гуй вызывать `Platform.runLater(runnable)`? Если бросается исключение про поток, значит, вы лезете в гуй вне `runLater`.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Я просто думал, что если в runLater заходить из другого потока, то будет использоваться как раз этот самый другой поток, а не поток FX. Недооценил я этот метод)